# Text Box summing is giving me incorrect total

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Good morning, all. So, I have 4 text boxes that are being summed and the total displayed in 1 text box. I'm getting a total, but it's doing more than addition and giving me the wrong total value. I'm not sure why, unless it is parsing incorrectly. Any help would be much appreciated. I've attached a screenshot of what it is doing as well as my code below. [You can see with this picture the total is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr5QJ.png)

Thanks to you all,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() 
{

    var v1 = form1.txtCu2Row.value;
    var v2 = form1.txtCu3Row.value;

    var v3 = v1 + v2

    var v4 = form1.txtCu4Row.value;
    var v5 = form1.txtCu5Row.value;

    var v6 = v4 + v5



    form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = parseInt(v3) + parseInt(v5) ;


}
```

Comment: can you tell how you are calling myFunction and how form1 is referenced.

Comment: @SundarSingh thanks for responding. I'm calling my function via an on-change event.   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCu5Row" runat="server" Width="25px" Heighth="20" Height="18px" 
            CssClass="style40" CausesValidation="True" OnChange="myFunction()" ></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

Comment: provide your full code..please

Comment: @AnandSingh that is the full code for my function. I've also included a picture of the issue.

Comment: Before any addition, parse all values.

Comment: You are not using v6. Is your last line an error v3+v5 or should v5 be v6?

Comment: @mshsayem you think I should parse v1,v2,v4, and v5 before calling my totaling?

Comment: @MikeJenkins don't you think I need v6 to do my totaling for v4 and v5?

Comment: Only pointing out v6 appears unused in the function, so checking this wasnt an easy to fix typo in code

Comment: Thank you all, so very much. it appears parsing before totaling was the fix, although I'm not sure why. Thank you all, again!

Comment: @JTroy An explanation is in my answer.

Comment: @LGSon thanks so much for the explanation as well as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `parseInt` is necessary when read from for example an input as the value you get is a string representation of the number, and as such you can't calculate with it.

As soon as you parsed it, the variable will be an integer, which can be used for calculations, hence it works as expected.

Do like this.

```
function myFunction() 
{

    var v1 = parseInt(form1.txtCu2Row.value);
    var v2 = parseInt(form1.txtCu3Row.value);

    var v3 = v1 + v2

    var v4 = parseInt(form1.txtCu4Row.value);
    var v5 = parseInt(form1.txtCu5Row.value);

    var v6 = v4 + v5

    form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = v3 + v6;

}
```

And if you don't need all those variables, like this maybe.

```
function myFunction() 
{

    var v2 = parseInt(form1.txtCu2Row.value);
    var v3 = parseInt(form1.txtCu3Row.value);

    var v4 = parseInt(form1.txtCu4Row.value);
    var v5 = parseInt(form1.txtCu5Row.value);

    form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = v2 + v3 + v4 + v5;

}
```